# Is it possible to create an exit function in Delphi 2007?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I'm using Delphi 2007 and was wondering if the
following is possible, if not is it then
possible in another version of Delphi.

My code at the moment looks like `doo1` but what
I would like to have is something like `doo3`.

I've made `doo2` and it works but I'd prefer
having the `exitIfFalse` function in one place
instead of as a subprocedure in many places.

```
function foo(const bar: Word): boolean;
begin
  Result:= bar = 42;
end;

function doo1: integer;
begin
  if not foo(42) then begin
    Result:= 1;
    exit;
  end;
  if not foo(8) then begin
    Result:= 2;
    exit;
  end;
  Result:= 0;
end;

function doo2: integer;
  Procedure exitIfFalse(const AResult: boolean; const AResultCode: integer);
  begin
    if not AResult then begin
      Result:= AResultCode;
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
begin
  Result:= -1;
  try
    exitIfFalse(foo(42), 1);
    exitIfFalse(foo(8), 2);
    Result:= 0;
  except
    on e: EAbort do begin
    end;
  end;
end;

function doo3: integer;
begin
  exitIfFalse(foo(42), 1);
  exitIfFalse(foo(8), 2);
  Result:= 0;
end;
```

Comment: You can make 'exitIfFalse' non-local by passing 'Result' as a var parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That is a good approach to modify `Result`, but not to stop execution.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes that's smart one step closer, but I'd still need the try-except clause

Comment: Yeah. I didn't say it would be nicer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Later versions of Delphi (2009 and newer) come close: they let you write

```
function doo3: integer;
begin
  if not foo(42) then Exit(1);
  if not foo(8) then Exit(2);
  Result:= 0;
end;
```

Note how the new `Exit(value)` form can be combined with the more traditional `Result`.

Delphi 2007 does not support officially this, or anything similar.

A completely unsupported hack *may* work for you: Andreas Hausladen's [DLangExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/dlang/) (make sure to use an older build) provides this syntax for Delphi 2007 too.

Comment: The docs at http://andy.jgknet.de/dlang/ make no mention of the `exit` construct.

Comment: @Johan I already noted "make sure to use an older build". The last version is only for D2009, not for D2007, and does not add anything relating to `Exit` because D2009 already supports that natively.

Comment: @Johan From [Development snapshot builds](http://andy.jgknet.de/dlang/builds/): "**Removed:** Generics and extended Exit (both are superseded by Delphi 2009) **Removed:** Delphi 5-2007 isn't supported anymore. Only Delphi 2009" (last build) "**Added:** Exit(return value)" (two builds earlier)